# Product of Tori under antipodal equivalence

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, group-actions, fundamental-groups

Let $X=(S^1)^n$ be the product of $n-$circles (where $n>1$) and let $G=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ act on $X$ by $(-1).(x_1, \dots, x_n)=(-x_1, \dots, -x_n)$. What is the fundamental group of ${X}/{G}$?

Comment: What have you tried? There is a standard theory of fundamental groups of group quotients

Comment: @FShrike So I know there is an exact sequence $1 \to \mathbb{Z}^n \to \pi_1(X/G) \to G \to 0$ from the theory you mentioned, but what can I deduce from it about $\pi_1(X/G)$?

Comment: The mentioned theory also implies that $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is (isomorphic to) a normal subgroup of $\pi_1(X/G)$. Do you see how to proceed?

Comment: @VincentBoelens To be fair, there are at least two different groups which fit into that exact sequence, $\Bbb Z^n$ and $\Bbb Z^n\oplus\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$. There may be more, I'm unsure. I regret my original comment because I forgot the directions of the arrows and we actually only know (an explicit...) isomorphism $\pi_1(X/G)/\Bbb Z^n\cong\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$

Comment: @VincentBoelens If I knew that the fundamental group is abelian, then I could say that the short exact sequence splits since $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is free. But is it abelian? I don't know....

Comment: I think a better strategy is trying to show that $\mathbb{R}^n\to X\to X/G$ is the usual cover.

Comment: So then $\mathbb{R}^n \to X/G$ would be the universal covering and the fundamental group would be the group of deck transformations. I guess that the deck transformation is in some way generated by $\mathbb{Z}^n$ (as the action on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which gives us the torus) and $G$, but what is it exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $G$ is finite and $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the universal cover of $X$, the universal cover of $X/G$ is the composition $$\mathbb{R}^n\xrightarrow{q} X\xrightarrow{p} X/G,$$
where $q$ is the product of the exponential maps. If we let $\gamma$ be the linear path from $(0,\ldots,0)$ to $(\frac 12,\ldots,\frac 12)$, then $\alpha = (p\circ q)_\ast(\gamma)$ is an element of $\pi_1(X/G)$ which is not in $p_\ast(\pi_1(X))=\mathbb{Z}^n$. Since $p_\ast (\pi_1(X))$ has index $2$, any element of $\pi_1(X/G)$ not in $p_\ast(\pi_1(X))$ has the form $\alpha\cdot \beta$ with $\beta\in p_\ast(\pi_1(X))$. The action of $\pi_1(X/G)$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is given by $\alpha\cdot \beta \cdot x = x + (k_1+\frac 12,\ldots,k_n + \frac 12)$, where $\beta$ corresponds to $(k_1,\ldots, k_n)$ under the identification of $\pi_1(X)=\mathbb{Z}^n$. We see that $\pi_1(X/G)$ is abelian and has no torsion, hence is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^n$. In fact, we can identify it with the subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^n$ obtained by adding the generator $(\frac 12,\ldots, \frac 12)$ to $\mathbb{Z}^n$.